# Probability of intersection greater than product of probabilities?

Tags: probability

Is it true in general that $P(A\cap B) > P(A) P(B)$? If yes, why?

Comment: No, it's true that $P( A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$

Answer (score 5):

In general, nothing can be said about the relationship between $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A),P(B)$. For instance, when we roll a dice,

- If

  - $A$ denotes the event of getting an even number
  - $B$ denotes the event of getting an odd number
  - $A \cap B$ denotes the event of getting an even and odd number.

  We have $P(A)=1/2$, $P(B)=1/2$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0$, which means $P(A \cap B) < P(A) \cdot P(B)$.
- Similarly, if

  - $A$ denotes the event of getting an even number
  - $B$ denotes the event of getting a multiple of $4$
  - $A \cap B$ denotes the event of getting an even number and a multiple of $4$.

  We have $P(A)=1/2$, $P(B)=1/6$ and $P(A \cap B)=1/6$, giving $P(A \cap B) > P(A) \cdot P(B)$.
- Similarly, if

  - $A$ denotes the event of getting an even number
  - $B$ denotes the event of getting a multiple of $3$
  - $A \cap B$ denotes the event of getting an even number and a multiple of $3$.

  We have $P(A)=1/2$, $P(B)=1/3$ and $P(A \cap B)=1/6$, giving $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $A$ be "this coin flip comes up heads" and $B$ be "this coin flip comes up tails".